# Content downloading(CSS, JS etc) taking too much time which making loading too slow

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, performance, spring-mvc, downloading-website-files

I am working on a spring framework project optimization. Its taking 2 minutes+ to load. When I checked in
Network console, it was js, css content download which were the main reason. 200KB file taking 2 minutes to be downloaded. Every 1KB taking 2-8 Seconds to be downloaded(other files).

Generated .war file relocating those css, js files in webroot but nothing improved.Where should I investigate to find the delay in content download? Could modifying .jsp files directly in .war file be helpful? It's not in localhost, I am deploying it in User Acceptance Testing server(UAT).

Tech Stack : Spring framework, Angular, GWT.

Comment: Try to open your CSS or any other static file from the WAR in your web browser and check the speed. How you use the Spring-boot app? It is deployed to a Tomcat as a WAR? Or WebLogic server?

Comment: It's deployed to tomcat as a WAR.

Comment: The normal CSS file(500KB) of .war taking below 100ms in chrome while the same file in UAT taking 2 minutes to be downloaded.

Comment: So then you can create and deploy a test WAR to your UAT Tomcat which only contains a simple file: a big image or your CSS. Then check the speed. If the downloading speed from this test WAR is correct then something wrong in your app WAR. If not, then environment or network issue you have.